# Bash-completion doesn't work at all

Tags: bashrc

looks like there is something wrong with the bash-completion in my Ubuntu 16.04. Tried almost everything... reinstalled it, changed the `bashrc` file (below code), relaunched the terminal etc. Nothing seems to work.

Can somebody assist?

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more details. In what way is it not working? How did you reinstall it? How did you change the bashrc?

Comment: I assume `bash-completion`  is already installed. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you get output when you enter the command `complete`? If yes, it's probably a quite long list, so to share it you should ideally upload it to a pastebin like e.g. https://pastebin.com/